# undefined reference to exported function from kernel module

Tags: c, arrays, linux, struct

From user space I'm trying to get at an exported function from a kernel module that I am programming so that I can get to an array of structs so that I can iterate through that array to find out how many structs there are in the array.

kernel_mod.c

```
controller_struct_t ctrl_list[MAX_CNTRS];

struct controller_struct_t * get_ctrl_list(void)
{
    return &ctrl_list;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL(get_ctrl_list);
```

user_space.h

```
controller_struct_t * get_ctrl_list(void);
```

user_space.c

```
//MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
controller_struct_t *ctrl_list = NULL;


ctrl_list = get_ctrl_list();
```

I tried putting the `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` in the user_space.c file then I get `error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token`.  I can build the kernel module and I've verified that the function is exported.  As I mentioned earlier I would like to get a pointer to the `ctrl_list` so I can find out how many structs are in that array.  The error I'm getting is below.

```
 undefined reference to `get_ctrl_list()'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of kernel modules; and congratulations on writing your first successful kernel module!

On Linux, if you would like to verify that your kernel module is 'exported', you can also check the file '/proc/kallsyms' to see if your kernel module function is exported:

```
> grep get_ctrl_list /proc/kallsyms
```

So, if I understand correctly, you would like to iterate a linked list in kernel space from user space?

First, make sure you have a good understanding of an 'address space'. Each address space is a unique set of addresses from 0 (or NULL) to the highest possible address of the machine.

Address spaces should not be though of as 'overlapping' one another.  They are more like 'parallel universes'.  Each address space may have it's own unique "planet pluto"; however, each "planet pluto" is unique, and is totally unaware of the other "planet pluto"s that might exist in other address spaces.

The kernel has its own address space, where your kernel module lives, along with all other kernel modules and the kernel itself.  They all share the -same- address space.  This means that they can easily interact with each-other.  One kernel module might share it's linked list with another module.  Everyone must play fair, and by the rules (or bad things will happen).

Each *nix process generally has it's own address space, called a 'user space'.  However, if you have a variable 'pluto' in one address space, that variable (or it's address) has no meaning in another address space.

Hence, if you have the address of a linked list in kernel space, it is generally meaningless in -any- user-space.  A program cannot (generally) use that address to access the object from it's own user-space.

In order to access a parallel universe (or address space), you need some kind of 'worm-hole' into that universe (or address space).  Are there programmatically accessible wormhole-like structures to access other address spaces?

Yes!

For example, shared memory.  It is possible to allocate (or map) memory that is accessible to multiple address spaces (including the kernel).  Such a structure is ideal for an 'array', but perhaps somewhat confining for a 'linked-list' (but not impossible).

System calls also function as a worm-hole from user-space to the kernel-space; as also do 'ioctls'.

The root user can access kernel memory directly using /proc/kcore on Linux (perhaps the biggest worm-hole to the kernel of all!)

Comment: great thanks for the info!  i would like a pointer to the array of objects so i iterate through the array to find out how many structs i have in the array.  doing research is there a function like `copy_from_user` that would work the other way? i imagine i can just iterate through the array on the kernel side then return an int to userspace. thanks for the help!